# A simple database command using quick.db

Tags: node.js, discord.js, quick.db

**Question**

I'm kind of new to [quick.db](https://quickdb.js.org/) and I want to make a command to set values for a user by  `!add <@user> <value>` and when I use `!total <@user>` it shows all the values of the user in an embed. I've given my code below. It adds the values to the users but, doesn't show the values.

**My Code**

```
} else if (command == 'add'){
        const user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
        const theID = args[1];

        db.get(`claim_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}`);

        db.set('ID', theID);

        message.channel.send(`Set **${theID}** for **${user.tag}**`);

    } else if (command == 'total'){
        const user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;

        const newID = db.get(`claim_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}`);
        if (newID === null) newID === '0';

        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Total')
        .setDescription(`${newID}`)

        message.channel.send(embed)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically, you are setting `'ID'` to the db, and not the user data.

To fix this just change `db.set('ID', theID);` to `db.set(claim_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}, theID);` and then it will save the user data, not 'ID'.

Comment: Are you sure you have value?

Comment: yeah, I used `!add @user 123` and then `!total`

Comment: yeah. sorry I'm new to quick.db and I'm just using this on my test bot

Comment: Np, I'm rn thinking what's wrong with this

Comment: Can we talk on discord? My ID is .Ninja.#2208

Comment: Yeah sure, I sented friend request to you.